# Criar array através de função

Tags: php

Existe alguma forma de retornar um *array*, algo como:

```
$array = [
     "parcela" => "1",
     "valor"   => "100",
];
```

Utilizando a função abaixo? Eu preciso retornar um *array* com o número das parcelas e o valor.:

```
function calcParcelaJuros($valor_total,$parcelas,$juros=0){
   if($juros==0){
      $string = 'PARCELA - VALOR <br />';
      for($i=1;$i<($parcelas+1);$i++){
         $string .= $i.'x (Sem Juros) - R$ '.number_format($valor_total/$parcelas, 2, ",", ".").' <br />';
      }
      return $string;
   }else{
      $string = 'PARCELA - VALOR <br />';
      for($i=1;$i<($parcelas+1);$i++){
         $I =$juros/100.00;
         $valor_parcela = $valor_total*$I*pow((1+$I),$parcelas)/(pow((1+$I),$parcelas)-1);
         $string .= $i.'x (Juros de: '.$juros.'%) - R$ '.number_format($valor_parcela, 2, ",", ".").' <br />';
      }
      return $string;
   }
}



print(calcParcelaJuros(250,4,2));

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, podes retornar um array preenchido e depois usar isso para mostrar a informação, assim por exemplo

```
<?php

function calcParcelaJuros($valor_total, $parcelas, $juros = 0){
    $parcelado = [];

    if ($juros > 0) { // se for com juros, calculamos o valor contando com o juro
        $I = $juros/100.00;
        $valor = $valor_total * $I * pow((1 + $I), $parcelas) / (pow((1 + $I), $parcelas) - 1);
    } else { // senao é porque é sem juro
        $valor = $valor_total / $parcelas; 
    }

    // em vez de usar um ciclo, fazemos um array_fill, do indice 1 até ao numero de $parcelas e colocamos o valor
    $parcelado = array_fill(1, $parcelas, $valor);

    return $parcelado;
}

// presumo que ja tenhas as variaveis assim
$o_valor_total = 250;
$o_numero_de_parcelas = 4;
$o_valor_dos_juros = 2;

$parcelado = calcParcelaJuros($o_valor_total, $o_numero_de_parcelas, $o_valor_dos_juros);

foreach ($parcelado as $parcela => $valor) {
    $nota = ($o_valor_dos_juros > 0) ? "Juros de: {$o_valor_dos_juros}%" : "Sem Juros";
    $valor_formatado = number_format($valor, 2, ",", ".");

    echo "{$parcela}x ({$nota}) - R$ {$valor_formatado} <br />";
}
```

Eu prefiro criar as minhas funções tendo apenas 1 responsabilidade, sendo que o exemplo acima está só a função que faz o calculo das parcelas, teria outra para mostrar o resultado formatado como pretendido (que em cima é o `foreach`).

### Edit

Para adicionar a data de vencimento, podes fazer algo assim, embora, como diz no comentário, também podias fazer só um ciclo para preencher o array.

```
<?php

function calcParcelaJuros($valor_total, $parcelas, $data_primeiro_vencimento, $juros = 0){
    $parcelado = [];

    if ($juros > 0) { // se for com juros, calculamos o valor contando com o juro
        $I = $juros/100.00;
        $valor = $valor_total * $I * pow((1 + $I), $parcelas) / (pow((1 + $I), $parcelas) - 1);
    } else { // senao é porque é sem juro
        $valor = $valor_total / $parcelas; 
    }

    // em vez de usar um ciclo, fazemos um array_fill, do indice 1 até ao numero de $parcelas e colocamos o valor
    $parcelado = array_fill(1, $parcelas, ['valor' => $valor, 'juro' => $juros]);

    // adicionamos as datas entao depois, embora pudessemos fazer tudo no mesmo ciclo..
    foreach ($parcelado as $p => $parcela) {
        if (empty($data_vencimento)) {
            $data_vencimento = $data_primeiro_vencimento;
        } else {
            $data_vencimento = date_add($data_vencimento, date_interval_create_from_date_string('30 days'));
        }

        $parcelado[$p]['parcela'] = $p; // para manter o numero do pagamento
        $parcelado[$p]['data_vencimento'] = $data_vencimento->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    return $parcelado;
}

// presumo que ja tenhas as variaveis assim
$o_valor_total = 250;
$o_numero_de_parcelas = 4;
$data_primeiro_vencimento = date_create('2018-01-31');
$o_valor_dos_juros = 2;

$parcelado = calcParcelaJuros($o_valor_total, $o_numero_de_parcelas, $data_primeiro_vencimento, $o_valor_dos_juros);

foreach ($parcelado as $parcela) {
    extract($parcela); // usamos o extract para as chaves do array serem variaveis dentro deste foreach

    $nota = ($juro > 0) ? "Juros de: {$juro}%" : "Sem Juros";
    $valor_formatado = number_format($valor, 2, ",", ".");

    echo "{$parcela}x ({$nota}) - R$ {$valor_formatado} (Vence em {$data_vencimento})<br />";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, na verdade eu só preciso do valor, sem formatação mesmo.

Comment: Utilizando esta mesma função, é possivel trazer as datas com vencimento a cada 30 dias ? sei que não está na questão, mas só pra saber mesmo

Comment: Eu testei, até criou um array, mas veja como ficou, https://imgur.com/OJcLTxa

É possivel deixar como $array = [
     "parcela" => "1",
     "valor"   => "100",
];

Comment: Removi o 2o exemplo anterior e substitui por um que inclui a data de vencimento sendo extendida a cada 30 dias. Podes tambem ter mais 1 parametro depois ou antes do `$juros` para aceitar o intervalo de tempo entre cada vencimento.

Comment: perfeito @leite, você não imagina o quanto me ajudou. Muito obrigado.

Comment: mais uma unica dúvida, o índice do array, não deveria começar com [0] ?, porque este começa com [1] ?

Comment: o array_fill aceita como primeiro parâmetro o primeiro índice a usar, como é 1 o array começa com 1, embora pudesse ser 0 e o código mais a frente tivesse isso em consideração

Comment: Irei popular uma tabela utilizando Bootstrap table, todos os casos em que o array tem o 0 como Index, funciona, mas neste caso, que começa com 1, não populou. Nas sei se pode ser isso.. se for o caso de começar com 0, como posso fazê-lo?

Comment: Muda o array_fill pra começar em 0, podes ter de por o fim do array_fill como `$parcelas - 1`, mas tens de confirmar, tou no telemóvel agora e não posso. Mais a frente adicionas um +1 a linha `parcelado[$p]['parcela'] = $p;`

Comment: Também estou no telemóvel, mas já tento e retorno aqui . Obrigado pela prontidão..

Comment: não tens de por o -1